# Show database data based on drop down selection

Tags: php, oop

My **database table**:

```
TABLE `events` (
    `event_id` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `event_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `event_desc` TEXT,
    `event_location` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `event_requirements` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    `event_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
```

**The goal**: When an event is selected in a select drop down menu, I would like to show the rest of the database data, which belongs to the event in a div below.
**The attempt** to solve the problem (in a MVC architecture):
Controller

```
  function index()
  {
      $overview_model = $this->loadModel('Events');
      $this->view->events = $overview_model->getEventTypes();
      $this->view->render('events/index');
  }
```

Model

```
  public function getEventTypes()
  {
      $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM events");
      $sth->execute();

      $events = array();

      foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $event) {
          $events[$event->event_id] = new stdClass();
          $events[$event->event_id]->event_id = $event->event_id;
          $events[$event->event_id]->event_title = $event->event_title;
          $events[$event->event_id]->event_desc = $event->event_desc;
          $events[$event->event_id]->event_location = $event->event_location;
          $events[$event->event_id]->event_requirements = $event->event_requirements;
          $events[$event->event_id]->event_date = $event->event_date;
      }

      return $events;
  }
```

View

```
    <!-- start event type selection --> 
   <div class="event-selection">
     <label>Choose an event:</label>
     <select id="select-event-type">
        <?php foreach ($this->events as $event) {
            // Using the event's ID as a value makes it easier for us to look up the selected event.
            echo "<option value='" .$event->event_id. "'>" .$event->event_title."</option>";
        }?>
    </select>

    <script>
        (function ($) {
            // Here we set the JavaScript variable 'events' to a JSON-encoded copy of the array we passed to the template, or null (if there are no events).
            var events = <?php echo (count($this->events) > 0) ? "JSON.parse(" .json_encode($this->events). ")" : "null"; ?>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#select-event-type').change(function() {
                    if (events) {
                        // Now we can get the event details from the selected value.
                        var event = events[this.value];
                        $('#event-details').html(event->title);
                    }
                });
            });
        })($);
    </script>   

    <!-- Start event-details -->
    <div id="event-details"></div> <!-- /#event-details -->

</div><!-- /.event-selection -->
```

**UPDATE**:
In the console all the event's data is shown now in json format (Thank you so so much for that!). But there is still nothing outputted and when I change the event in the selection the data in the console does not update!

Comment: Have you tried to check if the conditional if(events) is happening?

Comment: *"I do not get any error messages and my page is completely broken"* - Are you in fact checking for errors? If so, how?

Comment: I did something like this: `if (events) {
                         <?php echo 'Hello'; ?>
                     }` and nothing changed. So I think this part is not run anymore.

Comment: I open the console and there are no errors and on my page there are no error messages displayed either. Is there another way to check for errors?

Comment: This is one way `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); // rest of code` and https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html - I think you're using CI, correct? Looks like it.

Comment: I set that for my whole application. So (if I understood that correctly) all errors, warnings etc. should be displayed. But in this case there are none (not on the page nor in the console).

Comment: `fetchAll()` that's PDO syntax. You are using PDO throughout your code, right? Not mixing `mysql_` or `mysqli_` anywhere?

Comment: yes! I am using PDO! I am not using Code Igniter though. I am using this framework: https://github.com/panique/php-login . I do not think that there is any mysql/mysqli mix up (although a very good idea) because everything else is working in my application (a blog with database requests etc.)

Comment: I think in the view after the select the error is somewhere because everything before the select (as well as the select) is working fine but nothing after. All other pages of my applictation function flawless as well.

Comment: Yeah, this one's a head scratcher indeed. I won't be able to help any further, but I did upvote your question, in hoping someone else will pick up on it. In the meantime, try `var_dump`'ing which could help pinpoint what's being passed or not, including viewing HTML source, *cheers*

Comment: I found an error in the view!! `(function ($) { var events = 
Notice: Use of undefined constant events - assumed 'events' in /views/events/index.php` and 

 `Catchable fatal error: Object of class View could not be converted to string in /views/events/index.php`

Comment: Your view must have an unclosed `<?php` because the PHP interpreter is trying to parse the JavaScript on your page.

Comment: Thank you for that remark! I cannot spot an unclosed php tag though. I think I messed up the " in this line `var events = <?php echo (count($this.events) > 0) ? "JSON.parse(" .json_encode($this->events). ")" : "null"; ?>`

Comment: I spotted the error! I needed to change this `(count($this.events) > 0)` to this `(count($this->events) > 0)`. Now the functionality works (in the console) but the values are not displayed!